# How can we measure the air quality index of our room?

Tags: air-filter, measuring, air-quality

My house is situated near a construction site and dust, particulates, etc gather in *really* quickly. My room is currently set up such that there are two different air filters running continuously around-the-clock.

The [Air Quality Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_quality_index#United_States) is a number which indicates how *healthy* or *unhealthy* the air is. For example, 0 - 50 is considered pretty good, whereas 151 - 200 is considered unhealthy, and 301 - 500 is considered hazardous.

Is there a way for us to measure the Air Quality Index of our room?

Comment: this is a really good question.  i wonder if there is some accessory that can be plugged into your air handler (if you have central air) that would be measuring this.  i doubt it would be cheap though

Comment: Google tells me you could get a PM2.5 meter for ~$800. That's just one of several components of AQI, so buying measuring gear probably isn't feasible. Probably your local government is the best folks to ask, they may have standards about construction dust, etc.

Comment: It sounds like your specific concern is indeed dust. Websearch for "diy dust air quality" finds a number of devices (including built-it-yourself versions if you're handy with electronics), and one company that will send you an DIY sampling kit and analyze the result. ($100 for total particulate count, I think). I do like the suggestion of finding out whether a local inspector can do a test for you as part of enforcement.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you local codes and the type of work being done, the construction contractor might be required to monitor her project's environmental impact.
As already stated, testing equipment can be expensive to purchase for private use, but Code Enforcement or the contractor might be able to help you out with a loaner of some type, or even perform an IAC test for you.
Great question.  Please let us know how it turns out.